# RegEx for splitting string

Tags: java, regex

```
Map<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

String strTest1 = "Q1 = '1PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR==' and q2 = 'v21PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR='";
String strTest2 = "Q1='1PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR==' and q2='v21PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR='";

String[] output = input.split("\\s+and\\s+");
        for(String s:output ){
            String [] params = s.split("=");

            String key = params[0].trim();
            String value = params[1].trim();
            fieldMap.put(key, value.substring(1, value.length()-1));        

        }
  System.out.println(fieldMap);
```

I have tried the above example, and it works fine for strTest1.
However, its not parsing for the strTest2.

> Expected output: {Q1=1PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR==,
>   q2=v21PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR=}

As we are splitting by = however it should not be eliminated from value

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is if use String [] params = s.split("\\s+=\\s"); then first test string will pass, but second will not.

Comment: Both strTest1 and strTest2 should pass

Comment: I'd get the position of the first "=" in the string, chop till there and then eliminate possible leading whitespace. For key extraction you do the opposite: throw away anything behind the first "=" and trim.

Comment: Maybe all you need is to pass `2` to the `split`? `String[] params = s.split("=", 2);`. See https://ideone.com/oLadYH

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting it by each '=' and you have 3 that messes up your further parsing.

```
    Map<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

String strTest1 = "Q1 = '1PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR==' and q2 = 'v21PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR='";
String strTest2 = "Q2='1PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR==' and q3='v21PAaEaO5Js+zUErWe1Ns8fR='";

String[] lines={strTest1,strTest2};
for (String input:lines){
  String[] output = input.split("\\s+and\\s+");
          for(String s:output ){
              String [] params = s.split("=",2);

              String key = params[0].trim();
              String value = params[1].trim();
              fieldMap.put(key, value.substring(1, value.length()-1));        

  }
}
System.out.println(fieldMap);
```

Comment: so you need to limit the tokens to two.